# Strategy Tester in Tradingview-Modified MACD

Tags: pine-script

How to create "Strategy Tester" in Tradingview using below Pinescript, below code just crossout line of red and green?

```
//@version=2
study("ModMACD crossout",shorttitle="MODMACD cross")

p = close
len = input(8,minval=1,title="Length")
f = (1.414\*3.14159)/len
a = exp(-f)
c2 = 2\*a\*cos(f)
c3 = -a\*a
c1 = 1-c2-c3
ssmooth = c1\*(p+p\[1\])\*0.5+c2\*nz(ssmooth\[1\])+c3\*nz(ssmooth\[2\])

len2 = input(13,minval=1,title="Length")

f2 = (1.414\*3.14159)/len2
a2 = exp(-f2)
c22 = 2\*a2\*cos(f2)
c32 = -a2\*a2
c12 = 1-c22-c32
ssmooth2 = c12\*(p+p\[1\])\*0.5+c22\*nz(ssmooth2\[1\])+c32\*nz(ssmooth2\[2\])
macd = (ssmooth - ssmooth2)\*10000000

len3 = input(3,minval=1,title="Length")

f3 = (1.414\*3.14159)/len3
a3 = exp(-f3)
c23 = 2\*a3\*cos(f3)
c33 = -a3\*a3
c13 = 1-c23-c33
ssmooth3 = c13\*(macd+macd\[1\])\*0.5+c23\*nz(ssmooth3\[1\])+c33\*nz(ssmooth3\[2\])

plot(macd, color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(ssmooth3, color=red, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the strategy tester, you should convert your script to a [strategy](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy).

Then use `strategy.entry()` to enter a trade and `strategy.exit()` or `strategy.close()` to exit a trade.

Comment: Thank you Vitruvius, I struggle to add entry and exit condition in following line which shows an error following function not found "ta.ema":                                                               
MACD = ta.sma(close, len) - ta.ma(close, len2)
aMACD = ta.sma(MACD, len3)
delta = MACD - aMACD

if (ta.sma(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MACDLE", strategy.long, comment="MACDLE")
if (ta.sma(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MACDSE", strategy.short, comment="MACDSE")

Comment: The script in your original question is written in `v2`. But the code you shared here in the comment is written in `v5`. So, better upgrade everything to `v5` and try again. Don't forget to change `//@version=2` to `//@version=5`.